# How to save and load two dimensional array with datetime objects?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

I have to following array:

```
[[0, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 14, 0)],
 [1, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 19, 0)],
 [2, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 16, 0)],
 [3, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 9, 0)],
 [4, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 13, 0)],
 [5, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 7, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 10, 0)],
 [6, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 19, 0)]]
```

and want to save that to disc and load it again. I tried the following approach but I get the error

> Unknown string format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
np.savetxt('test.txt', trips,fmt='%s')
loaded = np.loadtxt('test.txt',converters={1:mdates.datestr2num('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),2:mdates.datestr2num('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')})
```

The np.savetxt() command produces this txt:

```
0 2020-12-01 10:00:00 2020-12-01 14:00:00
1 2020-12-01 18:00:00 2020-12-01 19:00:00
2 2020-12-01 09:00:00 2020-12-01 16:00:00
3 2020-12-01 05:00:00 2020-12-01 09:00:00
4 2020-12-01 09:00:00 2020-12-01 13:00:00
5 2020-12-01 07:00:00 2020-12-01 10:00:00
6 2020-12-01 04:00:00 2020-12-01 19:00:00
```

Comment: tried `pickle`?

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` replace `-` with `.`

Comment: @Ajay this doesn't work either. Same error.

Comment: `('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` this is not required
;  you may need to give a `dtype=datetime64[ms]`